# Unable to input, e.g Scanner not working - Kotlin Notebooks Plugin on Intellij Idea

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I installed this plugin on Intellij Idea. Ordinary codes like println works, I can print it. But when I want to get an input, for example with Scanner, I can't find where to write the input.

I think Kotlin Notebooks plugin is a new plugin. There's not much about it on the internet. I searched and couldn't find it, so I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: guys please help?